# Upgrade magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.2

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2

How to upgrade Magento 2.3.1 to Magento 2.3.2 ?

Comment: Follow This : https://bit.ly/3n4i2kj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two main ways:

- If using command line composer, you can follow this guide:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html (I haven't tried yet with Admin)

With the command line and Open source version, on your local machine, you can follow:

1) `composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update`

2) Apply updates: `composer update`.

3) Clean the Magento cache `php bin/magento cache:clean` or `rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/*  generated/code/*`

4) Update the database schema and data `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: if i run `composer update` then all vendor third party and magento core module update right?

Comment: It's only magento core module update. About third party, it doesn't update.

Comment: It should update with `composer update` command.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Do you mean third party extension will update with composer update?

Comment: Give me the name of third party which didn't update?

Comment: Not all modules have composer update, like this module Plazathemes_Bannerslider.

Answer (score 3):

Please use below commands to upgrade from **2.3.1 to 2.3.2**

> (it is wise to keep backup of source code and database before upgrade)

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf generated/
chmod +x bin/magento
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: It work. Thank you!  But don't forget php before bin/magento.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out missing php, I have updated answer.

Comment: We don't have the `var/generation/` folder on Magento 2.3.x.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh sorry It was typo I know its generated directory in root now. I fixed it.

Comment: you can run `bin/magento` without `php`

Comment: @AmanSrivastava Yep I know but to avoid confusion I added it in the answer :)

Comment: @AmanSrivastava but some time it doesn't work without php

Comment: Mostly not work on windows environments :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official doc to do this from **Web Setup Wizard**:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html

First meet the [Prerequisites](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman.html).

Then, start upgrade by updating your public and private keys with your Magento 2 Open source account or Enterprise Edition Account.

Comment: Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I used to successfully update Magento 2.3.3 [EE] to 2.3.5 [EE] I have divided the steps into parts:

Follow Below URL:

https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2020/09/29/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-3-x-ee-to-2-3-x-ee/